# Unlocking asp.net membership user

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I am using asp.net membership in my application. I have set maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" in web.config. User is locked out after 5 attempts. When does locked user get unlocked. Do I need to create a page to unlock users or it is done automatically after some hours/days ?

Please suggest.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default, you'll need to create something to unlock the user. There's no automatic mechanism that unlocks users after a period of time.

Answer (score 3):

I found the easiest, "less pain later" ways was to create a custom Membership provider that implements some sort of auto-unlock behavior. With this method, you're also able to provide a way for the user to configure the timeout period via the web.config file.

[Stefan Schackow has an excellent tutorial](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/sample_chapter/article.php/c12747/Implementing-Automatic-Unlocking-in-ASPNET-20-SqlMembershipProvider.htm) available.